# OAuth2: Which flow to use?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

There appears to be four distinct flows in OAuth2, i.e. ([link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2)),

1. Authorization Code Flow - used with server-side Applications
2. Implicit - used with Mobile Apps or Web Applications (applications
   that run on the user's device)
3. Resource Owner Password Credentials - used with trusted applications
   such as those owned by the service itself.
4. Client Credentials - used with Applications API access.

If I'm developing a mobile application that will consume resources from its own API, i.e., the mobile app is developed by the same team developing the API, which of the four OAuth flows should I use and how?

Given my scenario, it sounds to me like option 3 is the way to go. If this is the case, would you adopt the following process:

1. Release you mobile app with the ClientId and ClientSecret stored on
   it (deemed okay as the application is trusted).
2. Ask the user to log into their account using cookie-based
   authentication (immediately deleting their username and password).
3. Cache the hash of their username and password returned in the
   response of the cookie-based authentication.
4. Use the cached username and password, along with the ClientId and
   ClientSecret, to request access and refresh tokens from the token
   endpoint of the OAuth server.

Doe this seem sensible? It would be good to know if I'm on the right track with the above thought process, or if I'm going something incredibly silly and ought to be doing this some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Resource Owner Password Credentials flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) would be okay for your case.

BTW, it is difficult for a mobile application to keep its client secret confidential ([RFC 6749, 2.1. Client Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1), [RFC 6749, 9. Native Applications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-9)). Therefore, in normal cases, a client secret should not be embedded in a mobile application. In other words, embedding a client secret is almost meaningless in terms of security.

Comment: Would I gain anything using Resource Owner Password Credentials flow over Implicit flow? Especially if the the client secret is almost meaningless in terms of security?

Comment: The main purpose of OAuth 2.0 is to enable a user of a service to allow a third-party application to access his/her data hosted in the service **without revealing his/her credentials** (ID & password) to the application. In that sense, Resource Owner Password Credentials flow is exceptional because in the flow a client application directly receives a user's credentials. Authorization Code flow or Implicit flow should be used if you don't want to allow client applications to receive a user's credentials directly.

Comment: @TakahikoKawasaki what flow should we use in the web if the client is (site itself)

Comment: @ANinJa I hear Implicit flow (RFC 6749, 4.2) is often used for the case.

Answer (score 1):

> 2- Implicit - used with Mobile Apps or Web Applications (applications
>   that run on the user's device)

If your application runs entirely on a mobile device then you are encouraged to use this flow as your mobile app can't be trusted to keep its client credentials secret.

Comment: Does this not mean I'll have to ask the user to input their credentials again every time the access token expires since Implicit doesn't support refresh tokens?

Comment: depends on your authorisation server. If your auth server allows the user to remain logged-in once logging in the first time, then although your app will need to request access tokens regularly, the user will not be prompted to login again until the login session (usually a cookie) ends. So it can be seamless to the user.

Comment: okay. I think that makes sense - new to security stuff like this!. Would I gain any extra security using Resource Owner Credentials over Implicit?

Comment: @iandayman is it good practice to not expire the user's token ?